# SSRS stored procedure with temp table

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I have a stored procedure which extracts data and dump into a temp table. I have created a ssrs report to extract data from the stored procedure. But I believe ssrs is not able to identify the temp table and retrieve data to the report because to test my report I dropped the stored procedure and re-created, but without executing the stored procedure I tried to run the report. But still it shows data. I want to know how ssrs identify the temp table and extract data to the report.

Comment: are you doing it on VS?

Answer (score 2):

There may be two possibilities.

The first is that even though you dropped the Stored Procedures you don't say that you dropped the Temp table. Depending on if you used **#Temp** or **##Temp**, the temporary table may persist.

The second possibility is that you are seeing the stored data from Visual Studio. If you check your RDL file location, there should be a **.DATA** file with the data that SSRS retrieves. Many times it will re-use this data if nothing has changed with parameters or query changes.

[image]